# C fork() and pipe(): process get stuck reading pipe?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, low-level

I'm practicing with fork() and pipes and I have a question: why does the second child process get stuck reading the pipe if I don't close the first pipe (first child - second child) in the parent process?

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void checkArgs(int n){
    if(n!=1){
        perror("Wrong parameters number");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

int isAConsonant(char c){
    char vowels[5]={'a','e','i','o','u'};
    int i=0,toRet=1;
    for(i=0;i<5 && toRet;i++){
        if(c==vowels[i]){
            toRet=0;
        }
    }
    return toRet;
}

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    checkArgs(argc-1);
    int pipe1[2],pipe2[2],sync[2];
    int pid1,pid2;

    if(pipe(pipe1)<0 || pipe(pipe2)<0 || pipe(sync)<0){
        perror("Error opening pipes");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if((pid1=fork())<0){
        perror("error during fork");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(pid1==0){ //first child
        close(pipe1[0]);
        close(sync[0]);
        char buf[3];
        int fDes=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);

        if(fDes<0){
            perror("Error opening file");
            exit(-1);
        }

        write(sync[1],"N",1);

        while(read(fDes,buf,3)==3){
            write(sync[1],"N",1);
            write(pipe1[1],buf,3);
        }

        write(sync[1],"S",1);
        close(sync[1]);
        close(fDes);
        close(pipe1[1]);
    }
    else{

        if((pid2=fork())<0){
            perror("error during fork");
            exit(-1);
        }
        if(pid2==0){ //second child
            close(pipe2[0]);
            close(pipe1[1]);
            char buf[3];

            while(read(pipe1[0],buf,3)==3){
                if(isAConsonant(buf[0])){
                    write(pipe2[1],buf,3);
                }
            }
            close(pipe2[1]);
            close(pipe1[0]);
        }
        else{   //parent
            close(pipe2[1]);
            close(sync[1]);

            //it does not work if not executed
            //close(pipe1[1]);
            //close(pipe1[0]);

            char toStart;
            read(sync[0],&toStart,1);
            while(toStart!='S'){
                read(sync[0],&toStart,1);
            }

            int fDes=open(argv[1],O_RDWR|O_APPEND,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
            if(fDes<0){
                perror("Error opening file");
                exit(-1);
            }

            char buf[3];

            while(read(pipe2[0],buf,3)==3){
                write(fDes,buf,3);
                write(fDes," ",1);
            }

            close(pipe2[0]);
            close(sync[0]);
            close(fDes);
        }
    }
}
```

These calls terminate the program correctly

```
close(pipe1[1]);
close(pipe1[0]);
```

inputF file:

```
abcdefghilmnopqrstuvz
```

**Strace screen for executing code without close(pipe1[0]) and close(pipe1[1]) in the parent process:**

strace for the parent process

```
execve("./pipe", ["./pipe", "inputF"], 0x7ffc458bc820 /* 54 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55ed3c675000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (File o directory non esistente)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=71886, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 71886, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7d0b895000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200l\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2000480, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7d0b893000
mmap(NULL, 2008696, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7d0b6a8000
mmap(0x7f7d0b6cd000, 1519616, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7f7d0b6cd000
mmap(0x7f7d0b840000, 299008, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x198000) = 0x7f7d0b840000
mmap(0x7f7d0b889000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e0000) = 0x7f7d0b889000
mmap(0x7f7d0b88f000, 13944, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7d0b88f000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f7d0b894500) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7d0b889000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55ed3a7d0000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7d0b8d1000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f7d0b895000, 71886)           = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
pipe([5, 6])                            = 0
pipe([7, 8])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f7d0b8947d0) = 11194
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f7d0b8947d0) = 11195
close(6)                                = 0
close(8)                                = 0
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "S", 1)                         = 1
openat(AT_FDCWD, "inputF", O_RDWR|O_APPEND) = 6
read(5, "def", 3)                       = 3
write(6, "def", 3)                      = 3
write(6, " ", 1)                        = 1
read(5, "ghi", 3)                       = 3
write(6, "ghi", 3)                      = 3
write(6, " ", 1)                        = 1
read(5, "lmn", 3)                       = 3
write(6, "lmn", 3)                      = 3
write(6, " ", 1)                        = 1
read(5, "rst", 3)                       = 3
write(6, "rst", 3)                      = 3
write(6, " ", 1)                        = 1
read(5, 0x7ffffab4a6a5, 3)              = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=11194, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
read(5, 0x7ffffab4a6a5, 3)              = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
+++ killed by SIGINT +++
```

strace for the first child process

```
execve("./pipe", ["./pipe", "inputF"], 0x7ffc458bc820 /* 54 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55ed3c675000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (File o directory non esistente)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=71886, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 71886, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7d0b895000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200l\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2000480, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7d0b893000
mmap(NULL, 2008696, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7d0b6a8000
mmap(0x7f7d0b6cd000, 1519616, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7f7d0b6cd000
mmap(0x7f7d0b840000, 299008, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x198000) = 0x7f7d0b840000
mmap(0x7f7d0b889000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e0000) = 0x7f7d0b889000
mmap(0x7f7d0b88f000, 13944, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7d0b88f000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f7d0b894500) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7d0b889000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55ed3a7d0000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7d0b8d1000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f7d0b895000, 71886)           = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
pipe([5, 6])                            = 0
pipe([7, 8])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f7d0b8947d0) = 11194
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f7d0b8947d0) = 11195
close(6)                                = 0
close(8)                                = 0
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "N", 1)                         = 1
read(7, "S", 1)                         = 1
openat(AT_FDCWD, "inputF", O_RDWR|O_APPEND) = 6
read(5, "def", 3)                       = 3
write(6, "def", 3)                      = 3
write(6, " ", 1)                        = 1
read(5, "ghi", 3)                       = 3
write(6, "ghi", 3)                      = 3
write(6, " ", 1)                        = 1
read(5, "lmn", 3)                       = 3
write(6, "lmn", 3)                      = 3
write(6, " ", 1)                        = 1
read(5, "rst", 3)                       = 3
write(6, "rst", 3)                      = 3
write(6, " ", 1)                        = 1
read(5, 0x7ffffab4a6a5, 3)              = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=11194, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
read(5, 0x7ffffab4a6a5, 3)              = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
+++ killed by SIGINT +++
pepys@pepys:~/Scrivania/lso/C/pipe/prova strana$ ^C
pepys@pepys:~/Scrivania/lso/C/pipe/prova strana$ ls
es  es.c  inputF  pipe  pipe.c  trace.11193  trace.11194  trace.11195
pepys@pepys:~/Scrivania/lso/C/pipe/prova strana$ cat trace.11194
close(3)                                = 0
close(7)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "inputF", O_RDONLY)    = 3
write(8, "N", 1)                        = 1
read(3, "abc", 3)                       = 3
write(8, "N", 1)                        = 1
write(4, "abc", 3)                      = 3
read(3, "def", 3)                       = 3
write(8, "N", 1)                        = 1
write(4, "def", 3)                      = 3
read(3, "ghi", 3)                       = 3
write(8, "N", 1)                        = 1
write(4, "ghi", 3)                      = 3
read(3, "lmn", 3)                       = 3
write(8, "N", 1)                        = 1
write(4, "lmn", 3)                      = 3
read(3, "opq", 3)                       = 3
write(8, "N", 1)                        = 1
write(4, "opq", 3)                      = 3
read(3, "rst", 3)                       = 3
write(8, "N", 1)                        = 1
write(4, "rst", 3)                      = 3
read(3, "uvz", 3)                       = 3
write(8, "N", 1)                        = 1
write(4, "uvz", 3)                      = 3
read(3, "", 3)                          = 0
write(8, "S", 1)                        = 1
close(8)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

strace for the second child process

```
close(5)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "abc", 3)                       = 3
read(3, "def", 3)                       = 3
write(6, "def", 3)                      = 3
read(3, "ghi", 3)                       = 3
write(6, "ghi", 3)                      = 3
read(3, "lmn", 3)                       = 3
write(6, "lmn", 3)                      = 3
read(3, "opq", 3)                       = 3
read(3, "rst", 3)                       = 3
write(6, "rst", 3)                      = 3
read(3, "uvz", 3)                       = 3
read(3, 0x7ffffab4a6a5, 3)              = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
+++ killed by SIGINT +++
```

Comment: Please paste console text as text (in a code block), not as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system won't report EOF on a pipe's read descriptor while there is any process that has the pipe's write descriptor open.  That includes the current process.  You must make sure that pipes are closed — lots of closes.

---

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD`

---

If the parent process will not communicate with any of its children via
the pipe, it must ensure that it closes both ends of the pipe early
enough (before waiting, for example) so that its children can receive
EOF indications on read (or get SIGPIPE signals or write errors on
write), rather than blocking indefinitely.
Even if the parent uses the pipe without using `dup2()`, it should
normally close at least one end of the pipe — it is extremely rare for
a program to read and write on both ends of a single pipe.

Note that the `O_CLOEXEC` option to 
[`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html),
and the `FD_CLOEXEC` and `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC` options to `fcntl()` can also factor
into this discussion.

If you use
[`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html)
and its extensive family of support functions (21 functions in total),
you will need to review how to close file descriptors in the spawned process
([`posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose.html),
etc.).

Note that using `dup2(a, b)` is safer than using `close(b); dup(a);` for a variety of reasons.
One is that if you want to force the file descriptor to a larger than
usual number, `dup2()` is the only sensible way to do that.
Another is that if `a` is the same as `b` (e.g. both `0`), then `dup2()`
handles it correctly (it doesn't close `b` before duplicating `a`)
whereas the separate `close()` and `dup()` fails horribly.
This is an unlikely, but not impossible, circumstance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So do I have to close all pipes in every process in this case?

Comment: You need to close all the unused ends of the pipes.  I'm not entirely clear what the sync pipe is for.  I haven't compiled or debugged the code.  I'm not completely sure what it is supposed to be doing.  I observe that child 1 sends two `N` messages to the sync pipe in a row — one before the loop and one during it.  I'm not sure whether that matters.  It feels like one too many, but feelings aren't reliable.  If the parent isn't using `pipe1` at all, it must close both ends for the children using it to detect EOF — your comments indicate you've found that out.

Comment: I recommend drawing the processes and all the pipes and standard I/O and any other file descriptors.  Make sure you know who does what with each one.  That's a minimum of 9, probably 10, maybe more file descriptors you need to chase.  (9 from 3 pipes plus the 3 standard I/O channels.) . If you can't work out what's happening with all of them, you need to study the code until you can.  You should eventually have 6 pipe-closing `close()` calls in each child and in the parent.  Granted, they are closed if the process exits, but you've got a problem with a process not exiting; you need to know.

Comment: The first child neither reads from nor writes to `pipe2`; it should close both ends of `pipe2` before it does almost anything.  It does correctly close the read ends of the pipes it does write to.

Comment: The second child neither reads from nor writes to the `sync` pipe; it should close both ends of `sync` before it does almost anything.  It does correctly close the unused ends of the pipes it does read from and write to.

Comment: The second child depends on detecting EOF from `pipe1`.  The parent process neither reads from nor writes to `pipe1`.  It is imperative that it closes both ends of the pipe so that child 2 can detect EOF.  And it needs to close that pipe early enough – before it starts iterating (which is where your commented out `close()` calls are; that's why it works when you include them and fails when you don't).

Comment: You probably mean `close(b); b = dup(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

> why does the second child process get stuck reading the pipe if I don't close the first pipe (first child - second child) in the parent process?

I don't fully understand at a short glance what your code does exactly, but essentially, you create three pipes first and then you fork twice.

This leaves you with three processes and three pipes. Each of your processes as a reading and a writing end of each of the pipes.

A pipe's reading end only signals EOF when all writers are closed. I supposed this isn't true in your situation.

Comment: The first child process reads 3 characters from inputF and passes them to the second child process that checks whether the first character is a consonant. If true, the second child process passes the characters to the parent process which writes them to inputF.

Comment: Okay, so I close pipe1 in the parent process. Why does the program end if I don't close the "sync" pipe in the second child process?